# Function not executing in telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

If I start the client at the beginning of the script

```
api_id = 123254534
api_hash = '124324235543'
client = TelegramClient('parslon', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
    
***
    
def three_step(message):
    url = ""
    url = message.text
    bot.send_message(id_chata, 'test..')
    thread_ = threading.Thread(target=kosat, args=(url,))
    thread_.start()

def kosat(url):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    channel = client.get_entity(url)
```

Then on the line - `channel = client.get_entity(url)` the script stops working further. My guess is that the problem is that the authorizes in the main thread, and this code is already running in another. But I'm not sure. I tried using async but it didn't work either.

In general, the code works if you put the client's authorization directly before `channel = client.get_entity(url)`. But I do not need it, because I get a Database error with several calls to the function.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stops working further"?  As far as I can tell, this code does nothing other than spawning a thread, that will do nothing other than set a local variable that will immediately vanish.  If there's an error message, we need to see the full traceback.  If it just doesn't do what you expect, we need to know what it actually did, and what you expected.

Comment: The script further performs several functions. I've only posted snippets of code where the bug is likely to be.

By "stops working further" it means that the script executes everything up to this function, and stops at it. He cannot process it.

Before and after the function, added print('1-2'). So before the print function, that's all. Then nothing just happens.

Comment: Do you find a solve for this? I have the same problem =(